# TOCO/Tensorflow .pb to .tflite output_arrays not working

Tags: macos, tensorflow, toco

I am relatively new to Tensorflow, and I have built a custom trained image model that is a retrained mobilenetv1 model. I currently have a .pb graph, and a labels.txt file.

I am trying to use TOCO to convert my .pb graph to a .tflite graph so I can use it with Firebase, and I keep getting an error when trying to run TOCO. The code I am running in terminal is:

```
./toco \
--input_file=/***/frozen_graph.pb \
--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--output_format=TFLITE \
--output_file=/***/newGraph.tflite \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--input_arrays=input \
--input_shapes=1,224,224,3 \
```

I have tried specifying the `--output_arrays` flag, but I don't know what to set for it. The error I am getting in terminal is:

```
F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/tooling_util.cc:1480] Check failed: model->flags.output_arrays_size() > 0 (0 vs. 0)This model does not define output arrays, so a --output_arrays flag must be given on the command-line.
Abort trap: 6
```

I have spent so many hours and hours trying to figure out what to set `--output_arrays` equal to, and I am stuck. I'm running MacOS 10.13.3. Please help meeeeeeeee thanks

Answer (score 0):

`--output_arrays` is a required flag in TOCO. Most MobileNetV1 models have an output array of `MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1`, however it may vary depending on your model. The best way to look into an output array is to use TensorBoard to visualize your graph.